# Azure Function to call multiple API endpoint at the same time

Tags: azure-functions

I've got an old azure function that's calling a REST API service from a supplier to get information about some products. It performs it in the old way with a for and only one call at time. I was wondering if it's possible to use Parallel.For setting a max degrees of concurrency and have the Azure Function to open more then one connection at time.

Is this possible? I was thinking of injecting the IHttpFactory and create HttpClient instances at needed.

Thanks

Comment: So it’s C#? How many endpoints do you want to hit at (pretty much) once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the hosting model, this will not have too much impact. Please see GitHub issue [C# Parallel.ForEach not excuting in parallel](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/815).

> The dynamic scale capabilities of Azure Functions will never take a single execution and transparently distribute that execution over multiple threads or machines. If you have a scenario where a large amount of work has to be done based on a single event then you should split your work up across multiple function executions so that the system can scale it out. One of the easiest ways to do this is with queues.

A solution for your scenario might be to use [Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview). The [Fan out/fan in Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview#fan-in-out) sounds like it might suit your needs.

> In the fan out/fan in pattern, you execute multiple functions in parallel and then wait for all functions to finish. Often, some aggregation work is done on the results that are returned from the functions.
>
> [image: A diagram of the fan out/fan pattern]
>
> With normal functions, you can fan out by having the function send multiple messages to a queue. Fanning back in is much more challenging. To fan in, in a normal function, you write code to track when the queue-triggered functions end, and then store function outputs.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of that... Taking a look, tanks